# Enviar datos de insert al enviar email

Tags: laravel

en mi controlador en el metodo STORE hago el insert a la BD pero adicional necesito enviar 2 correos electrónicos, uno a mi cuenta y otro a la cuenta del cliente que rellenó el formulario, estoy probando con un envio (a mi cuenta personal) y llega, pero necesito mostrar cierta información del insert que se hizo antes del envío, entonces hago el insert y me salta el error que dice que la variable $datos no existe, pero si ha enviado el correo...

Tengo asi el Store en el controlador:

```
$solicitud = new SolicitudServicio();
        $solicitud->fecha_solicitud = $request->fecha_solicitud;
        $solicitud->status = 0;
        $solicitud->detalle = $request->detalle;
        $solicitud->tipo_solicitud_id = $request->tipo_solicitud_id;
        $solicitud->cliente_id = $request->cliente_id;
        $solicitud->local_id = $request->local_id;
        $solicitud->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $solicitud->save();

        $datos = array(

            'ID Solicitud' => $solicitud->id,
            'Fecha de la Solicitud' => $solicitud->fecha_solicitud,
            'Detalle' => $solicitud->detalle,
            'Cliente' => $cliente = Cliente::find($solicitud->cliente_id)


        );

        //Enviamos los Emails al administrador y al cliente
         Mail::send('gestion.emails.nuevaSolicitud', $datos , function($message){
            $message->from('xxx@ssss.com', 'XeneixeGestion');
            $message->to('micorreo@gmail.com')->subject('Nueva Solicitud de Ticket');
         });
```

gestion.emails.nuevaSolicitud es una pantilla blade que seria la que se envia al email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nueva Solicitud de Servicio</h1>
    <p>se ha realizado una nueva solicitud de Servicio, los datos son los siguientes:</p>
    {{$datos}}
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedo pasar la variable $datos A LA vista para construir el email a enviar?

PD: Como podria hacer para enviar un segundo email en este store?

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el template obtienes los datos a través del nombre de la key que seteas en el array.

Por ejemplo si pasas esta variable como segundo parámetro del la funcion `Mail::send();`

```
$datos = array(
    'id_solicitud' => $solicitud->id,
    'fecha_solicitud' => $solicitud->fecha_solicitud,
    'detalle' => $solicitud->detalle,
    'cliente' => $cliente = Cliente::find($solicitud->cliente_id)
);
```

En tu template del mail accedes a esos datos de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nueva Solicitud de Servicio</h1>
    <p>se ha realizado una nueva solicitud de Servicio, los datos son los siguientes:</p>
    {{ $id_solicitud }}<br>
    {{ $fecha_solicitud }}<br>
    {{ $detalle }}<br>
    {{ $cliente }}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Por el lado de enviar el mail a las dos cuentas, con que agregues las dos al método `to()` en forma de array, debería bastar:

```
Mail::send('gestion.emails.nuevaSolicitud', $datos , function($message){
    $message->from('xxx@ssss.com', 'XeneixeGestion');
    $message->to(['micorreo@gmail.com','elotrocorreo@gmail.com'])->subject('Nueva Solicitud de Ticket');
});
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, me funciono!!!